# How can I open the User Account Control settings from command line

Tags: windows-7, uac

It should be something like **control APPLET.cpl**, but I am not able to find the applet name. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`C:\Windows\System32\UserAccountControlSettings.exe`

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are looking for the command to open the User Account Control applet from the Windows Run command. To do this, in the Run box type `useraccountcontrolsettings` then click <kbd>OK</kbd> to get directly to the User Account Control Settings window.

Answer (score 2):

You can also enable and disable via CMD:

**Disable:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v  EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

**Enable:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v  EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Sorry to necro this. But this regkey should not be tampered with. You see that it is a subkey of the path policies, which means there are a policy-settings to change this. (Local Policies\Security Options\User Account Control)